# Svg circle fill property isn't working on Chrome

Tags: angularjs, html, spring-mvc, d3.js, svg

I'm working with d3.js, AngularJs with ui.router and Spring MVC. I created a custom version of this graphic http://charts.animateddata.co.uk/datavistree/

I change the node's style to be filled with an image using patterns and everything work just fine.

When I change ui.router to work with html5 and the base tag, I also did some changes in my Server and everything was working fine but my graphic's nodes fill property is not working on Chrome, also in Microsoft Edge the nodes goes black, and belive me or not in Internet Explorer works!

So I make a new application without server, only using angular, ui.router with html5 and d3 and everything works!

A little bit of my Javascript

```
// Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(), links = tree.links(nodes);

    var defs = svg.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs");


    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    // Largo de los links
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 100;
        console.log(d);
        defs.append("pattern")
        .attr("id",d.identity)
        .attr("height", 40)
        .attr("width", 40)
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y", "0")
        .append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href",d.profilePicture)
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y","0")
        .attr("width", 40)
        .attr("height", 40);
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });



    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node")
            .attr(
                    "transform",
                    function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y0 + ","
                                + source.x0 + ")";
                    }).on("click", click);


    // Estilo del circulo al inicio de la carga(Animacion)
    nodeEnter.append("circle").attr("r", 1e-6).style("fill",
            function(d) {
                return d._children ? "url('#" + d.identity+ "')" : "url('#" + d.identity+ "')";
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base tag affects URLs (because that's what it's for) so your "url('#" + d.identity+ "')" does not match anything in the document any more as you're making relative URLs point somewhere else.

Internet Explorer is broken - works in your PoV is broken per the approperiate specifications. Edge, Chrome (and Firefox) get it right.

To fix this you could either use an absolute path or stop using the `<base>` tag.

An absolute path would look something like url('https://localhost:8080/" + *your html file name* + '#' + d.identity+ "')